# How to bind comma-separated string to List in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

In a html file, I am trying to get the fields and values in the following DTO using Thymeleaf:

```
ValuesDTO(serving=100.0, unit=G, energy=160.0, protein=5.0, totalFat=7.0)
```

So, how can I list values as the following? The labels are static, I just need to get the corresponding value by field name e.g. `energyAmount`

```
Energy: 160.0    --> get value of `energy` field
Protein: 5.0     --> get value of `protein` field
Total Fat: 7.0     --> get value of `totalFat` field
```

Comment: Can you show the html/thymeleaf code where you want to integrate it and the Java code where you set the attribute?

Comment: Do you really need to parse that comma-separated string? Or is that just the `toString()` result of a `ValuesDTO` Java object?